# Showing particular MySQL table fields for a single row

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with 8 fields/columns. Of these, 5 columns have either 0 or 1 as values.   I would like to show only those fields  whose value is 1 for a particular ro . 
The obvious method is to run a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE  field1=1 OR field2=1 OR field3=1 OR field4=1 OR field5=1 ;
```

This will yield a resultset containing 8 fields/columns where the conditions are satisfied.

But what I want to try is to run a query which gives a result-set containing only that  fields which has 1 as value.

Is it possible? 
If possible, how can I do this?

Comment: is there going to be only one field having the value 1?

Comment: @Majid No there are 5 fields/columns which will be having values either 1 or 0 . For any particular row I want to show only those columns which  have value 1.

Comment: But what will you achieve with this? How you are going to use such result set?

Comment: @Anuja Suppose the five fields are type of badges  given to any user . If the value of the field is 1  the user is assigned a badge . Now By using the resultset I can Directly show the badges assigned to a user .

Comment: @Abhishek but why not check the fields in your code? or do as I said in my response. But either way you'll have to do some work in the code. The solution I gave doesn't need you to add columns if you have new badges though.

Comment: @Majid I know how to do it  but was wondering If something could be done this way.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think this is possible. 
If you think about it when reading the resultset you'll have
to for example do :

```
$row[0]
```

Which will vary from row to row with what you're trying to do.
The result of `$row[0]` will always be 1 but the column selected
will differ from row to row, which is pretty confusing IMO.

A solution would be to change the design of the table and set:

```
visibleField1, visibleField2, visibleField3, visibleField4, visibleField5
```

and fill the column with the name of the field you want to show.

or name the field `visibleFields` and fill it with `"field1,field2,field5"` when you want to show those three

There's probably other ways to do this design change.

Answer (score 0):

You could try it like this:

```
SELECT id, 
CASE
WHEN field1 = 1 THEN 'badge_name'
WHEN field2 = 1 THEN 'other_badge_name'
...
END AS badge
FROM your_table
```

You can see an example at the link below that uses a couple stack overflow badges:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/189061/1